How can I calculate the cross-section of a $N+\pi \rightarrow N + \pi$?
In the same theme as my previous question, I have the diffusion process $$N+\pi \rightarrow N + \pi$$ where the Lagrangian for this theory is
$$L = \partial^\mu\psi\partial_\mu\psi^* - M²\psi\psi^*-\frac{1}{2}\partial^\mu\phi\partial_\mu\phi- m²\phi^2 + g\phi\psi\psi^*$$
where $M$ is the mass for Nucleons $N$ without spin and $m$ is the mass for the mesons $\pi$.
Am I wrong or the matrix element $\mathcal{M}$ is equal to
$$\mathcal{M} = (-ig)^2\left(\frac{-i}{s+M^2-i\epsilon}+\frac{-i}{u+M^2-i\epsilon}\right)$$
If I am correct, how can I do to get $|M|^2$ as a function of $\theta$ (and maybe something more), where $\theta$ is the scattering angle?

why do you have two propagators? At tree level, this interaction should require two vertices, between which there is only one nucleon propagator.

@paulina is what the exercise asks to calculate. :(

Is the formula you wrote given in the exercise?

Yes. (more words to send the message xD)

i am a fool. there are two ways for this interaction to take place, and the matrix element is the sum of these. your situation is very similar to compton scattering, except that all involved particles seem to have neither charge nor spin.

Is it too much to ask for a resolution of the problem?? I am kind of stuck in the way to do this...


$N \pi \to N \pi$ is a scattering process and not a diffusion process. 2. Nucleons are fermions, they do have spin. 3. Your Lagrangian does not describe the interaction of a fermion with a scalar but of a complex scalar $\psi$ with a real scalar $\phi$. 4. Interpreted in this way, the relative sign of the kinetic terms of $\psi$ and $\phi$ is wrong. 5. If your problem is simply how to relate a Mandelstam variable to a scattering angle and how to compute the absolute square of a complex number, it is not "too much to ask" for, but a pure homework problem, being off-topic on this site.

